# In Tensorflow, what is the difference between all trace_level in the member of tf.RunOptions

Tags: tensorflow, timeline

When i use the following code to generate timeline, I select `trace_level` as FULL_TRACE. But I want to know what is the difference between all the Class Members.

```
sess.run(predict , feed_dict=xxx ,options= tf.RunOptions(trace_level=FULL_TRACE ))
```

Class Members in tf.RunOptions is at the following link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RunOptions

```
FULL_TRACE
HARDWARE_TRACE
NO_TRACE
SOFTWARE_TRACE
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

`FULL_TRACE=HARDWARE_TRACE+SOFTWARE_TRACE`

`SOFTWARE_TRACE` only provide massage for `tf.layers`.

`HARDWARE_TRACE` provide how `tf-kernel` is assigned to hardware(layer turn into TF operations).